# C# Webclient().OpenRead is connection is returning a 404 error when I download too quickly

Tags: c#, .net, http

I'm making a little app that will display the current radar images for my area.  The images are publicly available in this web folder:
https://radar.weather.gov/ridge/RadarImg/N0R/MPX/

OK, no problem.  I have a method that reads the folder and parses out the links inside, than downloads them one at a time like this:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
Stream stream;
foreach (string file in folderList)
{
client.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", " en-US");
client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/6.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)"); // Get something sane for the server, or it rejects the connection.
stream = client.OpenRead(file);
//Do something with the stream data
stream.Flush();
stream.Close();
}
```

It can download one file just fine.  It can download multiple files, up until it gets to about the fifth file, then it throws up an error

> The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

That, seems to be a lie.  The file is actually there and if I copy-paste the file link into a browser, it loads right up.
If I add a System.threading.thread.sleep(10000); to get it to pause ten seconds between each file, it never errors out.

So am I doing something really stupid here with my webclient, or is this just how radar.gov enforces throttling?

Comment: The server side might be rate limiting you.

Comment: I'd suggest moving your `client.Headers.Add` calls **outside** of the loop.

Comment: That server has no limitations on the number of files you can download (just tested multiple requests in sequence; it downloaded 39 files, up to `MPX_20190905_0619_N0R.gif`). You're using the Stream the wrong way and, BTW, `//Do something with the stream data`and, **after** that, `Flush()`? You need to create a new Stream with a `using` statement, then read it to the end. Or don't use `OpenRead()` and just write the Stream to a File. Note that this is just the more visible mistake.

Comment: Interesting.  It's not the webserver entirely, it's something about the Stream process.  If I download the file, it works fine.  If I stream it, it has issues.  I don't want to download the file to disk because this will be running on a raspberry pi with an SD card and I'd rather run everything off ram.  Time for a clever hack around.